# Display warning alert and close session when the browser is closed

Tags: javascript, php

The web page is displayed upon redirection from another website and the URL changes during this process to point to a different port number.

1. So, I would like the JavaScript to detect if the URL is correct.
2. If the user closes the browser/tab, display an Alert Box with warning message.
3. Run PHP script to close the user Session

My code is:

```
if (window.location.href === "http://abc123.net.au:2048 ") {
    $(function () {
        try {
            opera.setOverrideHistoryNavigationMode('compatible');
            history.navigationMode = 'compatible';
        }
        catch (e) {
        }

        function OnBeforeUnload() {
            $(window).onbeforeunload;
            // Post to script that will log the user out
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "../logscript.php", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }

        function ReturnMessage() {
            return "Wait, by closing this session I will end your session. You will be required to log in again t access the site.";
        }

        function UnBindWindow()
        {
            $(window).unbind('beforeunload', ReturnMessage);
        }

        $(window).bind('beforeunload', ReturnMessage);
    });
}
else {
    document.write('<div>code is not working</div>')
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: On first question exactly what you want URL in correct format or match with your value

Comment: Add `xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }` before `xmlhttp.open` and try. Mention error you are facing. Script running?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please format your code (making proper indentations, removing unnecessary blank lines etc) before posting. Poorly formatted code is pretty tough to read and drives away people who could potentially answer your question. Are you getting any errors while executing your code? If yes, specify the exact error that you get because that helps a lot in debugging. Finally, you don't really have to say *I have problems with my code*. It is understood :)

Comment: I have also reworded the title to better explain your problem based on my understanding. Please feel free to edit if need be.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to your second work order:

```
window.onbeforeunload = bunload;

function bunload() {
    dontleave = "Are you sure you want to leave?";
    return dontleave;
}
```

Comment: ie; The URL would be logged in from http://abc123.net . Once logged in the URL will change to http://abc123.net.au:2048 which is the URL to be checked when the user decides to close the browser/tab.

Comment: Have you tried  match() or test() Function if not then try with that function and i think you know logic.